# SWRL to owl axiom

Tags: rdf, owl, swrl

I am new in OWL. I need to know how to convert the following rule in SWRL to OWL axioms.

RULE:

Taxon(?x), Taxon(?y), family(?y, "Myctophidae"), scientificName(?x, "Mirounga leonina") → is_predator_of(?x, ?y)

Where:

"Taxon" is a class, "family" and "scientificName" is a Data Type Propery and "is_predator_of" is a Object Property.

I read some post about how you can get to solve the conversion but I can not do it in Protégé, even using the plug in ROWL, any contribution will be welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: 1. Not all rules can be converted to OWL, this should be quite obvious. 2. Your rule contains unary and binary predicates in the premise and a binary predicate in the conclusion, thus, you would have to use something that is called **rolification**, which means to "The rolification of a concept `A` is a (new) role `RA` defined by the axiom `A ≡ ∃RA.Self`"

Comment: I'm not sure about the data property predicates in your rule. Maybe you'll need some additional class for each, because in the end, you have to use a property chain axiom which does only exist for object properties.